# Resolving unintended string behavior in C

Tags: c, string, type-conversion

I'm writing some simple C programs to learn the language, and so far I think I'm starting to get the basics, but I came across a strange behavior that I don't understand. Can someone tell me what's going wrong here and how to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const unsigned int MAX_LENGTH = 20;
    char str[MAX_LENGTH];
    unsigned int len = 0, i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
        str[i] = getchar();

        if (strncmp(&str[i], "\n", 1) == 0) {
            break;
        }

        len++;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        char whitespace[len];

        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            whitespace[j] = ' ';
        }

        printf("%s%c\n", whitespace, str[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I typed in "Hello World!" as the input for the looping `getchar()` method, and I expected the console to look something like this:

```
Hello World!
 e
  l
   l
    o

      W
       o
        r
         l
          d
           !
```

But instead I got this gibberish:

```
Hello World!
 ;oQ?e
  oQ?l
   Q?l
    ?o

      W
       o
        X?Pr
         ?Pl
          Pd
           !
```

Comment: Why is code using `if (strncmp(&str[i], "\n", 1) == 0)` instead of `if (str[i] == '\n')`?   Maybe something I am missing.

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out. Like I said I'm new, so I tried ``str[i] == "\n"`` and when the build yelled at me I looked up string compare and found that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`whitespace` array is not null terminated.

add a null terminator after the `for` loop, as

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        whitespace[j] = ' ';
    }
whitespace[j] = `\0`;
```

Comment: I just tested and this works. If you don't mind me asking, why does it need to be assigned to the ``j``th index when a whitespace is already in that index? I would think it would overwrite the whitespace but it doesn't.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts because, the foor loop exits when `j` is _not less than_ `i`, that means, `j` has already been increased as a part of `for` loop iteration., essentially equal to `i`.